# Custom fields do not appear in profiles for anonymous users

Tags: profile, contributions, contribution-page

I am running 4.5.2 Civicrm on a Drupal 7 installation and I have the following issue:

I have created a couple of donnor's pages with Civicrm contribute pages. 
In this pages I have included a couple of customized fields but **these fields are not being shown to users that are not logged in** (as an admin I can see them, but not as an anonymus user). Can you give a clue as to where the problem may be?

This have been my steps:

- First, add the custom fields to the contacts tab using the Admin > Screen and Custom Fields > Custom Fields. (Fields added to Contacts tab)
- Then, added to the profile that is going to be used on the Contribution Page
- Then create and make public the contribution page.

I know that there can be a number of setup problems at any of these steps, but since it is quite hard to give all the specs, I'd like to get suggestions as to where start looking and I will update the question with more info. Thanks in advance

Comment: Glad you sorted it out. Could you close your question and mark your answer as correct?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Our developer found the answer. It was an ACL problem. We fixed this adding a ACL where all roles can edit custom groups of fields.

Answer (score 2):

You can also check your Drupal permissions. (The path is admin/people/permissions.)

If you are happy for all custom data fields to be available to the public, look for the CiviCRM permission "CiviCRM: access all custom data" and make this available to anonymous users as well as authenticated.

Heather.

Answer (score 1):

Also found an easier way to do this. In the profile, you can set permissions to each field. Didn't realize this at first because both default and custom fields had the same permissions, and part of them were visible to not registered users and part of them --custom fields--were not.

Anyway, problem solved.